# How to have one node in two or three cluster using visjs

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

How can I cluster a node in two different clusters?

for example:

```
var nodes = [
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4', cid:[1]},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5', cid: [2]},
    {id: 6, label: 'Node 6', cid:[1,2]},
    {id: 7, label: 'Node 7', cid:[1]}
]
```

Node 6 should be present in both cluster 1 and 2. How can I achieve this?

I tried adding `joinCondition` like below:

```
var clusterIds = [1,2];

for(var i = 0; i < clusterId.length; i++){
    options[i] = {
        joinCondition:function(nodeOptions) {
            return (nodeOptions.cid.indexOf(clusterId[i]) > - 1);
        }
    }
    network.cluster(options[i]);
}
```

but I am getting the node only in one cluster.

Comment: I think this isn't possible because it doesn't seem to make sense... Why would you need a node to be in two clusters?

Comment: I am grouping/clustering the nodes by services so there are many chances that one node can be part of two or more services. So i need to show them in different clusters